# how can i display image from url?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a string variable `tmpImgURLStr` which contains URL like `www.abc.com/img.png`. i want to display that image in my imageView for that i have use some code but it's not working which is given below:

```
NSLog(@"Img URL === %@",tmpImgURLStr);

NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tmpImgURLStr]]]; 

UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
[logoImg setImage:myimage];
```

Comment: as far as i can see theres no problem in the code.. May be your URL does not contain any image. Please try debugging whether all contains data or is something null in between(may be logoImg is not allocated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your url - you have pdf, not an image. Usually `WebView`s are used for displaying this sort of data.

**Update**

Your `NSData` initiation is kinda too long. You can actually initiate a URL without supplying formatted string:

```
NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpImgURLStr]];
```

Also I've noticed that your URL is without protocol. You may want to try adding `http://` or `https://` to it and then see what happens. And just in case check if your `logoImg` is actually wired to the `NSImageView` in your NIB.

Comment: Yes your notice is perfectly right it's because of missing of http:// or https:// i have resolved it by adding this lines Thank you Very Much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.chakrainteractive.com/mob/ImageUpoad/pic2-2.png"];

NSData *imagedata = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imagedata];

[logoImg setImage: image];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of yours .. May be it will work..

```
logoImg=[[IUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,460)];
NSLog(@"Img URL === %@",tmpImgURLStr);
NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpImgURLStr]]];
UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
[logoImg setImage:myimage];
```

-Happy coding....