# ios - download and view image from web url xcode

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i need download image from url and load it into UIIamge view

first i get image from URL , but data return with nil i dont know why ?

```
 -(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
        UIImage * result;
    // data here return with nil 
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
        result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

And simply use: `- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;`

Or something more complex:

```
UIImageView image;
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[image setImageWithURLRequest:request
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                            // Succes on loading image
                       }
                       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                            // Fail to load image
                       }];
```

Comment: what you mean by image here ?

Comment: no visible @interface for UIImage declare  setImageWithURLRequest , this must be library method

Comment: you need to add the library to project and _#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"_

Comment: i add it and still have same problem , how can i make my variable belong to this class

Comment: you move it in _@interface_ . And btw _image_ is a UIImageView not UIImage sorry.

Comment: i think we have anther problem , setImageWithURLRequest:url this dosnt accept url site its need NSURLRequest am i right ?

Comment: right.. it's hard without IDE.. _NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];_ and replace the _url_ with _request_ as parameter in the method

Answer (score 2):

You can set your image from URL link like this:

```
  NSString *your_url = @"http://your_link/";
  image_View.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:your_url]]];
```

Also refer :

1) [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528244/how-to-display-image-on-uiimageview-using-url-and-nsstring-in-ios)

2) [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115643/how-can-i-display-image-from-url)

3) [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287860/how-to-load-url-image-in-image-view-in-iphone)